# Page sizing issues HTML

Tags: html

I am currently trying to build a [personal profile page](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/%7Ems18g18/). It's a work in progress, and I know little HTML, but I'm getting there.

I'm having an issue with my webpage with regards to how it scales with changes of the browser window size. On my (quite wide) screen at university, it looks fine. However, reducing the browser window size manually - or simply viewing it in a full size browser window on a smaller screen - appears to mess everything up - it doesn't look very nice. Text goes close to my pictures, and it all looks a bit tatty.

I think this is probably because my design is quite poor.

> **1. Is it because my design is bad or is there something else I'm doing blatantly wrong?**

My current idea for a solution is to resize things so that they would look more reasonable on a smaller screen (i.e. on a normal sized laptop). I'm worried that this might end up making things look a bit odd on a bigger screen, though.

> **2. Is it possible/within reason for a beginner to have two different designs, one for smaller screens and one for big screens, which could be detected and then utilised depending on what screen size viewer is using? Should my page be designed to simply work with whatever screen size?**
>
> **3. If I do reorganize the page such that it works better with smaller
> screens, is there a way to "lock" this design in place, so that it
> doesn't get messed up if someone views my page in a wider window?
> Perhaps a way to ensure that only the boundaries of the page increase
> in width?**

What I'm essentially asking is how I should go about designing my page in order to resolve the evident issue - where the issue is that it looks rubbish when the browser window is any smaller than the max size of my screen at university.

Comment: Hi Matt, you might want to read about responsive web design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created your page using tables. It is not a good practise nowadays exactly due to the problems your are facing. In practise, tables should not be used for layout purposes.

To make your layout fluid it'd be better to develop using div with float and relative positioning.

You can see another discussion related to this topic here 
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6036/why-arent-we-supposed-to-use-table-in-a-design/6037

Answer (score 0):

You could use css property @media, to handle different styles for different screen width: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp